# Change site date format to "24 October 2011" (day month year)

Tags: site, regional-settings

How do you change the date format for all the dates shown in a site to be in the format "day month year"? So that today would show as "24 October 2011"? I've gone to Site Actions > Regional Settings, but not sure what to select on this page. Thanks.

Comment: did you find answer to this post? we have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You could create a webcontrol which shows the date like you want it. In case of a date in a list, you should use a content query webpart with a custom xsl

If you want to show the date like you want it in a list:

Create a Date column(Call Date1), leave it on the default view
Then create another column for your text version date
Call it what ever you want "Date 2" or something
Select Calculated (calculation based on other columns) type
Down in the Formula window insert this formula: 
TEXT([the name of your number date column goes here between the square brackets],"mmmm-dd-yyyy"), Click "Ok", 
essentially you have the following in brackets =TEXT(Date1,"dd-mmmm-yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible, although a bit hacky. Check-out this blog post: http://dotnet.lv/blogs/antonsm/archive/2008/12/21/change-date-format-in-sharepoint.aspx

I have been using this method a couple of times and it has worked fine in my cases.